# Как получить ip пользователя

Tags: javascript, php, html, ip

Есть следующая форма:

```html
<form>
  <div class="col-12">
    <input type="name" class="name-form" name="name" data-name="Имя" placeholder="Ваше имя" required="" minlength="3" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <input type="tel" class="tel-form" name="tel" data-name="Телефон" placeholder="Номер телефона" required="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <input hidden name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" class="hidden-input" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" onclick="yaCounter47297391.reachGoal('zayavka'); return true;" class="btn">отправить заявку</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <p class="lock"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> гарантируем неразглашение Ваших данных</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Проблема в этой строке:

`<input hidden name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" class="hidden-input" />`

Мне необходимо, чтобы эта строка передавала IP того кто оставит заявку, но на почту приходит следующее...Подскажите, в чем ошибка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файл не обрабатывается PHP-интерпретатором. Расширение файла какое? Переименуйте в `.php` или [добавьте правило через .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Comment: Переименовал, но проблема осталась

Comment: Запускаете на сервере?

Comment: Вся эта фигня работает на конструкторе сайтов